# Tensor product of quotient and kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

In my problem I have a PID $R$, elements $0\neq a,b\in R$ and a map $\phi_a:R\rightarrow R$ where $r\mapsto ar$. Assuming I have done all my previous calculations right I need to prove that
\begin{equation}
\ker(\phi_a)\otimes_R R/bR = 0.
\end{equation}
I have been trying for quite some time now, could someone lend me a hand with a hint?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I solved it already. Since $R$ is a PID it is an integral domain, thus $\ker(\phi_a)=0$ and thus the tensor product is zero.

Comment: Oops, valid point, $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be nonzero.